# How do I achieve this using pdo prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, output, prepared-statement

In mysqli server I use this code below to select column specified by the url code:

```
       include "init.php";

       $get=$_GET["action"];

       $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $get ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");

       $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

       if ($productCount > 0) 
       {

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

       $id = $row["id"];

       $jjode = $row["code"];

       $product_name = $row["network"];

       $details = $row["details"];

       $logo = $row["logo"];

       $price = $row["price"];

       }
```

i try using it in my pdo server like code:

```
       include "init.php";

       $get=$_GET["action"];

       $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,code,network,details,logo,price FROM $get ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");

       $sql->execute();

       $row = $sql->fetchAll();
        if(count($row) > 0)

       {

       $id = $row["id"];

       $jjode = $row["code"];

       $product_name = $row["network"];

       $details = $row["details"];

       $logo = $row["logo"];

       $price = $row["price"];

       }
```

but it did not output a better result please how do i achieve that using pdo thanks in advance

Comment: [PDO examples. Selecting multiple rows](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#multiple)

Answer (score 0):

Both of code listings are not safe. Use whitelist for $get.

You should loop result of fetchAll

```
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row)

{

   $id = $row["id"];

   $jjode = $row["code"];

   $product_name = $row["network"];

   $details = $row["details"];

   $logo = $row["logo"];

   $price = $row["price"];

}
```

Comment: Please how do i Use whitelist for that $get

Comment: For example create array with allowed table names `$allowedTables = ['my_table1', 'my_table2']` and chech that `$get` exist in this array before preparing query.